# Unique column header

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

```
public class ReportSummary
{
    public void CreateHeader()
    {
        var header = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Description", "Summary By Role*"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName1" , "Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName2" , "Non Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName3" , "Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName4" , "Non Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName5" , "Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName6" , "Non Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName7" , "Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName8" , "Non Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName9" , "Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName10" , "Non Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName11" , "Public"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ColName12" , "Non Public")
        };

        for (int index = 0; index < header.Count; index++)
        {
             row[index] = header[index].Value;
        }
        AddRow(_currentRow, row, rowStyleIndex);    
    }


    void AddRow(int rowIndex, object[] cells, params int[] styleIndexes)
    {
        if (cells != null)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < cells.Length; columnIndex++)
            {
                int styleIndex = 16;
                //If style idex is defined, pass it, or else pass the default style index 16, which is a bold header with white background
                if (styleIndexes != null)
                {
                    styleIndex = styleIndexes[columnIndex];
                }

                AddCell((uint)rowIndex, columnIndex + 1, cells[columnIndex], styleIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

class ExcelProcessor :

```
public class ExcelProcessor2010
{
    protected Cell AddCell(uint rowIndex, int columnIndex, object cellValue, int styleIndex)
    {
        //Removing the values for the Greyed out cell and Empty cell
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(cellValue)) || styleIndex == 33)
        {
            cellValue = " ";
        }

        Cell cell = AddCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, cellValue);
        cell.StyleIndex = (uint)styleIndex;
        return cell;
    }

    protected Cell AddCell(uint rowIndex, int columnIndex, object cellValue)
    {
        Cell cell = null;
        if (cellValue != null)
        {

            string cellValueAsString = cellValue.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValueAsString))
            {
                cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(GetColumnName(columnIndex), rowIndex);
                if ((cellValue is bool || cellValue is bool?))
                {
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.Boolean;
                }
                else if (cellValue is DateTime || cellValue is DateTime?)
                {
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.Date;
                }
                else if (cellValue is string && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)cellValue))
                {
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.SharedString;
                }
                else if (cellValue is byte || cellValue is byte? ||
                            cellValue is sbyte || cellValue is sbyte? ||
                            cellValue is short || cellValue is short? ||
                            cellValue is ushort || cellValue is ushort? ||
                            cellValue is int || cellValue is int? ||
                            cellValue is uint || cellValue is uint? ||
                            cellValue is long || cellValue is long? ||
                            cellValue is ulong || cellValue is ulong? ||
                            cellValue is float || cellValue is float? ||
                            cellValue is double || cellValue is double? ||
                            cellValue is decimal || cellValue is decimal?
                    )
                {
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                }

                if (cell.CellValue == null)
                {
                    cell.Append(new CellValue
                                    {
                                        Text =
                                            cell.DataType != CellValues.SharedString
                                                ? cellValueAsString
                                                : InsertSharedStringItem(cellValueAsString)
                                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.CellValue.Text = cellValueAsString;
                }
            }
        }

        return cell;
    }

    protected string InsertSharedStringItem(string text)
    {
        // If the part does not contain a SharedStringTable, create one.
        if (SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable == null)
        {
            SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
        }

        int i = 0;

        // Iterate through all the items in the SharedStringTable. If the text already exists, return its index.
        foreach (SharedStringItem item in SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
        {
            if (item.InnerText == text)
            {
                return i.ToString();
            }

            i++;
        }

        // The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem and return its index.
        SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(text)));
        //SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Save();

        return i.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am generating Excel file using OpenXML. I am trying to create a table in Excel as shown in image:

[image]

But its changing column headers from Public/NonPublic to Public1, NonPublic2, Public3, NonPublic4 etc... After some research understood that Excel is expecting unique column headers. But it's happening only when you create Excel using OpenXML. If you create Excel manually and set headers like these then it works fine.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @Thirisangu : added sample code

Comment: There is no _Column Header_  section in Excel. It is the combination of `Rows` and `Columns` . And `Debug` your _AddCell_ method which may combine the `Values` with _Column Header_ (Cell).

Comment: No, its not... In that excel file I have some other tables having unique column names and it works fine for them. The issue is with common/ duplicate column name.

Comment: Can you show the code of your `AddCell` method?

Comment: @petelids : code added